# How to force MR execution when running simple Hive query?

Tags: hive, mapreduce

There is Hive 2.1.1 over MR, table `test_table` stored as sequencefile and the following ad-hoc query:

```sql
select t.*
  from test_table t
 where t.test_column = 100
```

Although this query can be executed without starting MR (fetch task), sometimes it takes longer to scan HDFS files rather than triggering a single map job.

When I want to enforce MR execution, I make the query more complex: e.g., using `distinct`. The significant drawbacks of this approach are:

1. Query results may differ from the original query's
2. Brings meaningless calculation load on the cluster

Is there a recommended way to force MR execution when using Hive-on-MR?

Comment: Unclear what you meant by "enforcing MR". Hive query is always converted into MR job. The other point is, if reducer is needed for that job. In case of a simple "select", the MR job consists of mapper only (i.e. no reducer)

Comment: @mangusta in case of simple `select *` query hive executor may fallback to "fetch task" instead of "map-only task", so MR is not triggered at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hive executor decides either to execute map task or fetch task depending on the following settings (with defaults):

- **hive.fetch.task.conversion** ("more") — the strategy for converting MR tasks into fetch tasks
- **hive.fetch.task.conversion.threshold** (1 GB) — max size of input data that can be fed to a fetch task
- **hive.fetch.task.aggr** (false) — when set to true, queries like `select count(*) from src` also can be executed in a fetch task

It prompts me the following two options:

1. set **hive.fetch.task.conversion.threshold** to a lower value, e.g. 512 Mb
2. set **hive.fetch.task.conversion** to "none"

For some reason lowering the threshold did not change anything in my case, so I stood with the second option: seems fine for ad-hoc queries.

More details regarding these settings can be found in [Cloudera forum](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Why-Map-job-is-launched-when-I-run-SELECT-FROM-tablename/m-p/158651/highlight/true#M121046) and [Hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `set hive.execution.engine=mr;` before your query and it will enforce Hive to use MR.

Comment: "Hive 2.1.1 over MR" suggests using MR engine, the root of the problem is not in the engine selected