# Why does Java OutOfMemoryError occurs when selecting less columns in hive query?

Tags: hive

I have two hive select statements:

```
select * from ode limit 5;
```

This successfully pulls out 5 records from the table 'ode'. All the columns are included in the result. However, This following query caused an error:

```
select content from ode limit 5;
```

Where 'content' is one column in the table. The error is:

```
hive> select content from ode  limit 5;
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
```

The second query should be a lot cheaper and why does it cause a memory issue? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you select the whole table, Hive triggers Fetch task instead of MR that involves no parsing (it is like calling `hdfs dfs -cat ... | head -5`).

As far as I can see in your case, the hive client tries to run map locally.
You can choose one of the two ways:

1. [Force remote execution with `hive.fetch.task.conversion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62536792/9145106)
2. [Increase hive client heap size using `HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS` env variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58952236/9145106)

You can find more details regarding fetch tasks [here](https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2016/02/18/make-hive-query-faster-with-fetch-task/).